# add default value to column after migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I created a column in a table as normal and did rake db:migrate. I then realised that I needed to set a default value for the column. After looking on stackoverflow I found several people that said all I had to do was edit the migration file so that this

```
def change
  add_column :accounts, :equipment_visible, :boolean
end
```

turns into this

```
def change
  add_column :accounts, :equipment_visible, :boolean, default: true
end
```

I did this then ran rake db:migrate again but nothing happened.

I kept looking on for answers as I assume it didn't work because I had already run rake db:migrate.

I then ran another migration and put this into the file;

```
def change
    def up
      change_column :accounts, :equipment_visible, :boolean, default: true
    end

    def down
      change_column :accounts, :equipment_visible, :boolean, default: nil
    end
  end
```

but still nothing has happened....does anyone know how I can go about this now?

Many thanks

*EDIT

The schema for the table is like this:

```
create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "crafts_visible",    default: true
    t.boolean  "equipment_visible"
  end
```

I am trying to get the "equipment_visible" to have default: true after it like the "crafts_visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rollback your migration and migrate db again:

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

or just run `redo` task:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo
```

Comment: That still hasn't done anything...the schema still does not show the column as having a default value...

Comment: @camillavk what console output does `bundle exec rake db:rollback` produce? And the second question: What content do you have in your migration file by now? Because the second version, with `def up` and `def down` method definitions, is incorrect.

Comment: I still have the def up and def down methods in the last migration file I created...what should it be instead of that? The first migration file is back to how it was originally without "default: true"
bundle exec rake db:rollback produces: AddDefaultValueToEquipment: reverted

Comment: @camillavk you messed it up a little bit. Now: Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, modify your migration file (it should have `add_column :accounts, :equipment_visible, :boolean, default: true` in `change` method) and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo`.

Comment: do I just leave the second migration file as it is then? Or did you mean that I should rollback twice?

Comment: @camillavk oh, I didn't notice, you did it in another migration. I'm not sure then, but my proposition is: run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, then: `bundle exec rake db:rollback STEP=2`, then delete your additional (this incorrect one) migration file and then again: `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
change_column_default :accounts, :equipment_visible, true
```